# How do I select the next error selection in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

[Build systems](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) and plugins can highlight errors (e.g. compile errors) in your code, creating red selections.

How can I jump to the next/previous error selection?

Answer (score 5):

After many a day, I have found the [answer in the build systems manual](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html#capturing-error-output-with-file-regex):

> When error information is captured, you can navigate to error instances in your project’s files with <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Shift + F4</kbd>. If available, the captured error message will be displayed in the status bar.